# Use OpenNN for score matching

Tags: generative-models, score, density-estimation, estimation

I‘m new to this topic and need some guidance. I would like to implement score matching (like sliced-score matching: https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.07088) in C++. OpenNN (https://www.opennn.net/) seems to be a good library, but is it capable of implementing score matching? The tutorials (https://www.opennn.net/documentation/) are unfortunately only given for classification problems and things like that.